# GLSL image2D antialiasing

Tags: opengl, glsl, image-unit

Is it possible to set MSAA sampling for image2D? Can it be of multisampled  type as texture2D in OpenGL? I am writing first pass not to a render buffer (or texture) but to image where I store several pixel copies of the same primitive but at different offsets.Then I blit it to the main window frame buffer.The output has a strong aliasing and I wonder if it's possible to make the first pass to use MSAA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an `image2D` cannot be multisampled.

[An `image2DMS` can however; indeed, it *must*.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Image_variables) Remember: multisample textures represent a fundamentally different texture type from 2D textures. They're just as different from 2D textures as 3D textures are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `glTexImage2DMultisample` instead of `glTexImage2D` for your render-to-texture target.

In the shader that you use for blitting the texture to the screen, use a `sampler2DMS` instead of a `sampler2D`, and `texelFetch` instead of `texture2D`.

You'll have to call `texelFetch` several times, one per sample, and average yourself.

Comment: He's not talking about textures. He's talking about Image Load/Store. That's why he said `image2D` and not `texture2D`.

Comment: Ohh, my bad, I misread the question ! (which is sad, because it heavily insisted on image2D)

Comment: I  can blit  without shader as well   ;)